SSIS Foreach Loop Container Hangs When More than 2 Variables are Assigned
I have a 2017 SSIS package with a Foreach Loop Container that iterates over an ADO Recordset.  The iteration works fine when I assign only 1 or 2 result columns to variables; however, if I try to assign 3 or more result columns to variables then the container hangs without any error.  The yellow gear keeps spinning, but the tasks inside the container are not executed.
I get the same results when I convert the recordset to an enumerable variable and iterate over the variable.
My workaround is to concatenate the query result columns with a delimiter inside the query so that only 1 column is returned, assign it to a string variable, and then split it into separate variables using Expression tasks inside the Foreach Loop Container.
Is this a bug in SSIS, or am I missing something?

Is it possible to a reproducible example to check this?
